# If-statment, that loop / rerun it self till one of the conditions is true is that possible? i

Tags: c#

Im totaly new to programming and trying to find a basic solution, im making a very simple game and im giving the person 2 options to do something, and if they choose neither 1 or 2 i want the tell them to choose again. But cant find a way to do it.

```
int antalspelare = 0;

int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out antalspelare);
if(antalspelare == 1)
{
   string spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
}
else if(antalspelare == 2)
{
    string spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
    string spelareTva = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Use a switch with a case for 1 and 2 and let the default handle the last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep on learning! You'll need loops to accomplish that. In particular here `while` loop will be useful that will keep running until the condition is false.

```
int antalspelare = 0
while(antalspelare < 1 || antalspelare > 2) 
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter option (1 or 2):");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out antalspelare);
        if(antalspelare == 1)
        {
           string spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if(antalspelare == 2)
        {
            string spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
            string spelareTva = Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

At first `antalspelare` is 0, and so `antalspelare < 1 || antalspelare > 2` is true, we start first iteration of the loop. It prints the message, asks to read number. If the number is 1 or 2, does the action, and on the next iteration `antalspelare < 1 || antalspelare > 2` is false, the loop will terminate. However if it was something not 1 or 2, then the loop will continue to ask for new number

Further, you can dedicate the loop only for reading `antalspelare`, and only after the loop continue all the logic, like so:

```
int antalspelare = 0
while(antalspelare < 1 || antalspelare > 2) 
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter option (1 or 2):");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out antalspelare);
}

string spelareEtt, spelareTva;
if(antalspelare == 1)
{
     spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
}
else if(antalspelare == 2)
{
     spelareEtt = Console.ReadLine();
     spelareTva = Console.ReadLine();
}

// You can use spelareEtt and spelareTva here and further
```

Comment: But if someone enters 3 then the first one is true, or if someone enters 0 the second one is true right? Then i wont get the result of 1 or 2? And if i do a whileloop can i still access the value variable?

Comment: @KimPersson If someone enters 3, you'll first run through the checks `if == 1` and `if == 2`, and none of those are true, then another iteration of the loop will start and `antalspelare > 2` will be true, so the loop continues, and the user will be asked again. If someone enters 1, you go into `if == 1` branch, and then on the new iteration of the loop `antalspelare < 1 || antalspelare > 2` will be false and the loop will stop. In case you want to preserve the variables `spelare`, then look at what I added to the answer